# How to pluck id of has_one associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Post
  has_one :latest_comment, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Comment'
end
```

I want to do something like:

```
Post.joins(:latest_comment).pluck('latest_comment.id')
```

but it's not valid syntax and it doesn't work.

```
Post.joins(:latest_comment).pluck('comments.id')
```

Above works but it returns ids of all comments for a post, not only of the latest.

Comment: This query is backwards. If you just want comment ids you want to just start the query off the Comment model and add a grouping or `DISTINCT ON` the `comments.post_id` column. On Postgres for example you can do `Comment.order(:post_id, created_at: :desc).pluck(Arel.sql('DISTINCT ON (post_id) id'))`. On MySQL I believe you can use something like `Comment.group(:post_id).order(created_at: :desc).ids` as it is less concerned about stuff like the order and group clause matching the select clause.

Comment: Please add answer with `Comment.order(:post_id, created_at: :desc).pluck(Arel.sql('DISTINCT ON (post_id) id'))` so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Assocations are a very leaky abstraction around SQL joins so your `has_one :latest_comment` assocation won't actually return a single row in the join table per record unless you're calling it on an instance of Post.

Instead when you run `Post.joins(:latest_comment).pluck('comments.id')`you get:

```sql
SELECT "comments"."id" 
FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
```

ActiveRecord isn't actually smart enough to know that you want to get unique values from the comments table - and it actually just behaves like a `has_many` association. In its defence this isn't actually something thats even realistic to do in polyglot fashion.

What you want to do can instead is to select the rows from the comments table and get distinct values:

```sql
Comment.order(:post_id, created_at: :desc)
       .pluck(Arel.sql('DISTINCT ON (post_id) id'))
```

`DISTINCT ON` is Postgres specific. The exact approach here will vary between RDBMS:es and there are many other alternatives such as lateral joins, window functions etc depending on your performance requirements.

Comment: It should be noted that this is hardly the most performant option - but its probally good enough. If it becomes a bottleneck use a lateral join or add a `posts.latest_comment_id` column.